# Can not create AVD in Lollipop android-5

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

I have installed Android API version 21 (lollipop), since i have been trying to set up an AVD . There is no "new" button,instead there is a "Create" option . then no matter what configuration i set , AVD manager fails to create the emulator.I have checked for updates.No issue with OK button . I tried a lot of things ... Any clue ??

Answer (score 0):

Android 5.0 Lollipop has not been released by far. But it will be at 12th Nov at America time zone. So, the IDE downloaded from Android Developer site is the preview version. And, I tried it as you, but, I realized it was incomplete. And some features were unavailable. So, I have been waiting for the release version, Android 5.0 Lollipop and its IDE bundled with ADT and Eclipse. Hopefully, this will help.

Comment: OK that explains . thanks . tomorrow is the official launching right ?

Comment: Yeah，but for me, it's the day after tommorow:(